# sorting a array by key values in priority php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have a array with results. now i want to show the results in a grid in a sorted way. therefor i need to alter this array.

sort needs to be like this "order" - "pre-order" - "closed"
but then i also have a "sort" value so i want to first sort on the 3 open status types and then within these types on the sort value, example array:

```
            $arr = [
            0 => ['id'=>1, 'sort'=>2, 'status'=>'closed', 'name'=>'some name...'],
            1 => ['id'=>2, 'sort'=>1, 'status'=>'closed', 'name'=>'some name...'],
            2 => ['id'=>3, 'sort'=>3, 'status'=>'open', 'name'=>'some name...'],
            3 => ['id'=>4, 'sort'=>5, 'status'=>'pre-order', 'name'=>'some name...'],
            4 => ['id'=>5, 'sort'=>4, 'status'=>'closed', 'name'=>'some name...'],
            5 => ['id'=>6, 'sort'=>6, 'status'=>'pre-order', 'name'=>'some name...'],
            6 => ['id'=>7, 'sort'=>7, 'status'=>'pre-order', 'name'=>'some name...'],
            7 => ['id'=>8, 'sort'=>9, 'status'=>'open', 'name'=>'some name...'],
            8 => ['id'=>9, 'sort'=>8, 'status'=>'open', 'name'=>'some name...'],
            9 => ['id'=>10, 'sort'=>10, 'status'=>'closed', 'name'=>'some name...'],
            10 => ['id'=>11, 'sort'=>11, 'status'=>'closed', 'name'=>'some name...'],
        ];
```

i dit it by several loops adding the types to a new array checking the open status, but i can not make it work with the sort.

Comment: this is a fixed array or a sql query result ?

Comment: @r2get implementation of dupe page's advice: https://3v4l.org/VfNeH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An other way using [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php):

```
$result = [];
$status = ['open'=>1, 'pre-order'=>2, 'closed'=>3];
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $key = $status[$v['status']] . pack("n", $v['sort']);
    $result[$key] = $v;
}
ksort($result);
$result = array_values($result);
```

or without after all:

```
$result = [];
$status = ['open'=>1e5, 'pre-order'=>2e5, 'closed'=>3e5];
foreach ($arr as &$v) {
    $key = $status[$v['status']] + $v['sort'];
    $result[$key] = $v;
}
ksort($result);
$result = array_values($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `usort` to do this

```
$arr = [
    0 => ['id'=>1, 'sort'=>2, 'status'=>'closed', 'name'=>'some name...'],
    1 => ['id'=>2, 'sort'=>1, 'status'=>'closed', 'name'=>'some name...'],
    2 => ['id'=>3, 'sort'=>3, 'status'=>'open', 'name'=>'some name...'],
    3 => ['id'=>4, 'sort'=>5, 'status'=>'pre-order', 'name'=>'some name...'],
    4 => ['id'=>5, 'sort'=>4, 'status'=>'closed', 'name'=>'some name...'],
    5 => ['id'=>6, 'sort'=>6, 'status'=>'pre-order', 'name'=>'some name...'],
    6 => ['id'=>7, 'sort'=>7, 'status'=>'pre-order', 'name'=>'some name...'],
    7 => ['id'=>8, 'sort'=>9, 'status'=>'open', 'name'=>'some name...'],
    8 => ['id'=>9, 'sort'=>8, 'status'=>'open', 'name'=>'some name...'],
    9 => ['id'=>10, 'sort'=>10, 'status'=>'closed', 'name'=>'some name...'],
    10 => ['id'=>11, 'sort'=>11, 'status'=>'closed', 'name'=>'some name...'],
];

usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['status'] == $b['status']) return $b['sort'] - $a['sort'];
    else {
        if ($a['status'] == "open") return -1;
        else if ($b['status'] == "open") return 1;
        else if ($a['status'] == "pre-order")  return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
});

var_dump($arr);
```